# Twelve People In Two Rows

Tags: logical-deduction, logic-grid

I've spent a lot of time on this problem and could not arrive at a definite answer.

> There is only one correct way to arrange twelve people into two rows using the following rules:

Six people A,B,C,D,E and F are sitting in row-1 facing North, and six people P,Q,R,S,T and U are sitting in row-2 facing South, but not necessarily in this order.

Row-2 is above row-1, so every person from one row faces a different person from the other row.

The following information is known about them.

> 1) B is to the immediate left of C, who does not face Q. Q is third to the left of R.
>
> 2) Neither Q nor C sit at the ends. B is to the right of F and D.
>
> 3) D faces the person who is third to the right of T, who faces E.
>
> 4) P sits second to the left of the person who faces A.
>
> 5) S is not an immediate neighbor of P.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with:

```
PQRSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU       LEFT }}

ABCDEF | ABCDEF | ABCDEF | ABCDEF | ABCDEF | ABCDEF       {{ LEFT
```

> 1) B is to the immediate left of C, who does not face Q. Q is third to the left of R.
>
> 2) Neither Q nor C sit at the ends. B is to the right of F and D.

2 means we can easily remove Q and C. B cannot be in 1 or 2 (right of F and D), or 6 (left of C). F and D cannot be in 6. B cannot be in 5 (there is no C in 6). C cannot be in 2 or 3 (no B in 1 or 2). F and D can be removed from 5 (no B to the right).

```
P RSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU | PQRSTU | P RSTU       LEFT }}

A  DEF | A  DEF | AB DEF | ABCDEF | A C E  | A   E        {{ LEFT
```

> 3) D faces the person who is third to the right of T, who faces E.

T cannot be 1,2,3 (there is someone 3 to the right), E is 4,5,6.

From 1) Q is 4,5,6, R is 1,2 (not 3 as no Q in 6)..

```
P RS U | P RS U | P  S U | PQ STU | PQ STU | P  STU       LEFT }}

A  D F | A  D F | AB D F | ABCDEF | A C E  | A   E        {{ LEFT
```

> 4) P sits second to the left of the person who faces A.

Tells us A is not 5,6, P is not 1,2. E fixed, so we can remove it from the others, fixing C, so remove C too. B is 4 (from 1).

3) tells us T is facing E, so T fixed.

4) says A not in 4. 3) says D is 3, and so 4) says P not 5.

```
  RS U |   RS U | P  S U | PQ S U |  Q S U |     T       LEFT }}

A    F | A    F |    D   |  B    |   C    |     E        {{ LEFT
```

> 5) S is not an immediate neighbor of P.

S is not 3,4.

1) says Q not 5, therefore Q is 4, and R is fixed too.

SU lock in (2,5) says P is 3.

```
  R    |    S U | P      |  Q     |    S U |     T       LEFT }}

A    F | A    F |    D   |  B    |   C    |     E        {{ LEFT
```

4) gives A is 1. F is 2. 5 says S is not 2.

```
  R    |      U | P      |  Q     |    S   |     T       LEFT }}

A      |      F |    D   |  B    |   C    |     E        {{ LEFT
```

So:

> ```
> RUPQST
> AFDBCE
> ```

Answer (score 5):

Clue

> Remember the people in the top row have different lefts and rights to those in the bottom row

---

Solution:

> ```
> ECBDFA
> TSQPUR
> ```

Taking 1 and 2:

> (note there is an extra `?` at the start of exactly one of two lines, and one at the end of the other line or in the brackets if it is the first line)
>
> ```
> ?CB(FD)
> ?Q??R
> ```

Taking 3:

> `T` and `E` are at the first 3 of the top and bottom lines respectively, but the only place they can be is: (this also gives `D` and the `?` in the second spot of the second line)
>
> ```
> ECBD??
> T?Q??R
> ```

Now, by 4:

> `P` sits in the left of the two adjacent `?`s in the bottom since the second `?` faces `D`, and also then by 5 `S` is in the first `?` of the second line:
>
> ```
> ECBD?A
> TSQP?R
> ```

And finally:

> ```
> ECBDFA
> TSQPUR
> ```

Comment: If row 1 is facing North and row 2 is facing South along with row 2 being above row 1, shouldn't the solution have A,B,C,..  below P,Q,R,...  ?

Comment: @NimitBhardwaj It doesn't really matter, you can rotate the arrangements 180 degrees (since computer screens don't have north or south). I find it easier to visualise this way.

Comment: I tried solving the problem again using your rotate by 180 method and was able to solve it. However, I still cannot fix the positions of A,F and P,U when I keep row 1 below. Was this rotate by 180 method some trick to make the visualization easier or am I still missing something when trying to do it without rotating?

Comment: @boboquack Every 2D representation of directionality has north at the top, your people are facing the wrong way.

Comment: B is to the left of F and D in your solution when it should be to the right?

Comment: @obl those people are facing the other way, so their left and right corresponds to screen right and screen left respectively.

Comment: @Carl If you find it hard to visualise, you can suggest an edit, but I'm fine as it is.

Comment: @boboquack oook makes sense, have an upvote.

Comment: @NimitBhardwaj Try looking at it like this: \begin{align}R&U&P&Q&S&T\\A&F&D&B&C&E\end{align}